# Difference between media queries and javascript resize event

Tags: javascript, css, web, media-queries

What is the difference between media queries and the javascript resize event. Both of them looks quite similar.

Which pros and cons have media queries, and which the resize event?

Comment: Mhh... They are totally different, `resize` is a DOM event occurred when the viewport was resized. In Media Queries there are much more properties, than those connected to the viewport size. You can control the layout by the media, import style rules etc.

Comment: If you're talking about responsive design then I suggest you to keep as much as possible in CSS media queries to avoid implementing responsive logic in javascript. That's the purpose of media queries. Since we don't know what exactly you're trying to accomplish though it's hard to tell what's best for you.

Comment: I know that I should use media queries for responsive thinks and so on. But what is going on in the CSS engine?. My 'senior' use always javascript for navigation things and prefer javascript resize instead of media queries.

Comment: `CSS` load faster than `Javascript`.. javascript will work when the `html` is rendered.. if you load javascript `before` the `html` or the particular `html tag` is rendered it will not work. Thus `media query is better option`. P.S its time to change your senior way of using `resize` function.. :)

Comment: _“My 'senior' use always javascript for navigation things and prefer javascript resize instead of media queries.”_ - that’s probably more _senile_ than actually “senior”. Sounds like you are dealing with someone of the “that’s how we have always done it” variety - so probably not the best teacher ...

Comment: @CBroe yes we are often fighting each other. He uses `line-height` as padding for buttons and input fields wtf...

Answer (score 0):

> Media query is a CSS technique introduced in CSS3.
>
> It uses the @media rule to include a block of CSS properties only if a >certain condition is true.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking about `MediaQueryList` events and `window.resize` events, they're run at the same time except for what appears to be first paint:

```cpp
void Document::LayoutViewportWasResized() {
  MediaQueryAffectingValueChanged(MediaValueChange::kSize);
  if (media_query_matcher_)
    media_query_matcher_->ViewportChanged();
  // We need to be careful not to trigger a resize event when setting the
  // initial layout size. It might seem like the correct check should be
  // (load_event_progress_ >= kLoadEventInProgress), but that doesn't actually
  // work because the initial value of load_event_progress_ is
  // kLoadEventCompleted. DidFirstLayout() is a reliable indicator that the load
  // event *actually* completed; but we also need to fire a resize event if the
  // window size changes during load event dispatch.
  if (View()->DidFirstLayout() ||
      load_event_progress_ == kLoadEventInProgress) {
    EnqueueResizeEvent();
    EnqueueVisualViewportResizeEvent();
    if (GetFrame()->IsMainFrame() && !Printing())
      probe::DidResizeMainFrame(GetFrame());
  }
  if (!HasViewportUnits())
    return;
  GetStyleResolver().SetResizedForViewportUnits();
  SetNeedsStyleRecalcForViewportUnits();
}
```

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/a3beacbe1eaa89b5e1555fea8e017df4404d0904/third_party/blink/renderer/core/dom/document.cc#4581-4603

Avoiding an event firing always on resize vs sometimes probably has some minor benefits.

The only instance where you'd want to perhaps throttle the event from firing repeatedly is if a user is resizing a window with the mouse. Mobile/Tablet configurations that rotate likely only fire once.